# problem while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

Tags: android, gradle

I am building my project on android studio 4. I end up getting this error

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

i tried to check out other people with a similar problem. And for their case the solution was to add `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m` but i already have `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m`

Here is my error log stack sample

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)
```

I am really not sure where the problem is, and the gradle version i use is 6.1.1 and even when i try to change the version, i still get the same error

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you eventually find solution to this?

Comment: @BigO i just unistalled and installed another version of android studio. couldnt get the solution

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the same thing....

Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> /home/circleci/code/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_local.xml:374: AAPT: error: attribute anim_scale_factor (aka es.fiestasgranada.main:anim_scale_factor) not found.